# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'getQualityDetailList'

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have problem when i pass parameters to AJAX request for Web Method..
This shows an error " Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'getQualityDetailList' ". AJAX request is below..

```
SaveProductComplaint: function 
(failureCB,getQualityDetailList,getShortageDetailList,getPackageDetailList) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "ProductComplaint.aspx/SaveProductComplaint",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(ProductComplaintPage.ajaxDataObject,{'getQualityDetailList': getQualityDetailList ,'getShortageDetailList': getShortageDetailList ,'getPackageDetailList': getPackageDetailList }),
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg !== null && msg.d !== null && msg.d !== "null") {
                    var result = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    if (result.Exception) {
                        if (result.Type === GlobalMsgResource.Type_Error) {
                            ShowErrorMessage(result.Message);
                        } else if (result.Type === GlobalMsgResource.Type_Warning) {
                            ShowWarningMessage(result.Message);
                        }
                        else if (result.Type == GlobalMsgResource.Session_Timout_Error) {
                            ShowConfirm('Session timeout, please re-login.', {
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Error',
                                showCancelButton: false,
                                confirmButtonMethod: function () {
                                    window.location = "~/Login.aspx";
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (result) {
                        ShowConfirm('Your complaint against Complaint ID ' + result + ' has been registered...', {
                            type: 'success',
                            title: 'Success',
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonMethod: function () {
                                successCB(result);
                                showLoader(false);
                                //ProductComplaintPage.view.ResetControls();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    ShowErrorMessage(GlobalMsgResource.Something_Went_Wrong);

                }
                showLoader(false);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                failureCB(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
                showLoader(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Here is Function in which i'm assigning values for passing parameters in AJAX request..

```
 addProductComplaint: function () {
        //if ($(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.Form).valid()) {
            ProductComplaintPage.ajaxDataObject = {
                productcomplaintentity: {
                    ProductComplaintId: $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.txtProductComplaintId).val(),
                    CustomerId: $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.txtCustomerId).val(),
                    ComplaintPriority: $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.ddlComplaintpriority + ' OPTION:selected').text()
                }
            };
            var table1 = $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.dtQualityIssueDetail).DataTable();
            var getQualityDetailList = [];
            var qualityissuesallrows = table1.rows().nodes();
            if (qualityissuesallrows.length > 0) {
                $.each(qualityissuesallrows, function (index, value) {
                    var QualityIssueDetailEntity = {};
                    QualityIssueDetailEntity.barCode = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
                    QualityIssueDetailEntity.ProductComplaintId = $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.txtProductComplaintId).val();
                    QualityIssueDetailEntity.ItemName = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
                    QualityIssueDetailEntity.RatioOfProblem = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();
                    QualityIssueDetailEntity.Reason = $(this).find("td").eq(4).html();
                    QualityIssueDetailEntity.Suggestion = $(this).find("td").eq(5).html();
                    getQualityDetailList.push(QualityIssueDetailEntity);
                });
            }
            var table1 = $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.dtShortageIssueDetail).DataTable();
            var getShortageDetailList = [];
            var shortageissueallrows = table1.rows().nodes();
            if (shortageissueallrows.length > 0) {
                $.each(shortageissueallrows, function (index, value) {
                    var ShortageIssueDetailEntity = {};
                    ShortageIssueDetailEntity.barCode = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
                    ShortageIssueDetailEntity.ProductComplaintId = $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.txtProductComplaintId).val();
                    ShortageIssueDetailEntity.ItemName = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
                    ShortageIssueDetailEntity.ShortageSinceInMonth = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();
                    getShortageDetailList.push(ShortageIssueDetailEntity);
                });
            }
            var table1 = $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.dtPackageIssueDetail).DataTable();
            var getPackageDetailList = [];
            var packageissueallrows = table1.rows().nodes();
            if (packageissueallrows.length > 0) {
                $.each(packageissueallrows, function (index, value) {
                    var PackageIssueDetailEntity = {};
                            PackageIssueDetailEntity.barCode = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
                            PackageIssueDetailEntity.ProductComplaintId = $(ProductComplaintPage.controlIds.txtProductComplaintId).val();
                            PackageIssueDetailEntity.ItemName = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
                            PackageIssueDetailEntity.NoOfPieces = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();
                            PackageIssueDetailEntity.Problem = $(this).find("td").eq(4).html();
                            PackageIssueDetailEntity.Suggestion = $(this).find("td").eq(5).html();
                            getPackageDetailList.push(PackageIssueDetailEntity);
                        });
                    }

                    ProductComplaintPage.modelView.SaveProductComplaint(getQualityDetailList,getShortageDetailList,getPackageDetailList);
    //                if(getQualityDetailList != 0 && getQualityDetailList != '' && getQualityDetailList != null){
    //                    
    //                }
    //                else if(getShortageDetailList != 0 && getShortageDetailList != '' && getShortageDetailList != null)
    //                {
    //                    ProductComplaintPage.modelView.SaveShortageProductComplaint(getShortageDetailList);
    //                }
    //                else if(getPackageDetailList != 0 && getPackageDetailList != '' && getPackageDetailList != null)
    //                {
    //                    ProductComplaintPage.modelView.SavePackageProductComplaint(getPackageDetailList);
    //                }
                //}
            }
```

Here is my Web Method...

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static string SaveProductComplaint(ProductComplaintMasterEntity productcomplaintentity, List<ProductComplaintDetailQualityEntity> getQualityDetailList, List<ProductComplaintDetailShortageIssueEntity> getShortageDetailList, List<ProductComplaintDetailPackingEntity> getPackageDetailList)
        {
            ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("ErrorLog");
            try
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] == null)
                {
                    SessionSpecificException sse = new SessionSpecificException() { Reason = "Session timeout, please re-login." };
                    throw new SessionSpecificException();
                }

                clsProductComplaintMaster obj = new clsProductComplaintMaster();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                int max = obj.GetMaxProductComplaintId();
                productcomplaintentity.ProductComplaintId = max;

                productcomplaintentity.DataEntryUserID = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString().ToUpper();
                if (obj.Save(0, productcomplaintentity))
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IsAllowSMS"]))
                    {
                        nSendSMS(productcomplaintentity.CustomerId, productcomplaintentity.ProductComplaintId);
                    }
                    return max.ToString();
                }
                else if (getQualityDetailList.Count > 0 )
                {
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GTBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CRM_ProductComplaintDetailQualityTAB";
                            try
                            {
                                var reducedList = getQualityDetailList.Select(x => new { x.ProductComplaintId, x.Barcode, x.RatioOfProblem, x.Reason, x.Suggestion }).ToList();
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reducedList.AsDataTable());
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (getShortageDetailList.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GTBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CRM_ProductComplaintDetailShortageIssueTAB";
                            try
                            {
                                var reducedList = getShortageDetailList.Select(x => new { x.ProductComplaintId, x.Barcode, x.ShortageSinceInMonth, x.OrderQuantity, x.ShortageDate }).ToList();
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reducedList.AsDataTable());
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (getPackageDetailList.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GTBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100;
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CRM_ProductComplaintDetailPackingTAB";
                            try
                            {
                                var reducedList = getPackageDetailList.Select(x => new { x.ProductComplaintId, x.Barcode, x.Problem, x.Suggestion, x.NoOfPieces }).ToList();
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reducedList.AsDataTable());
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }
            catch (SessionSpecificException sse)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents.RemoveAll();
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    Exception = true,
                    Message = sse.Message,
                    Type = "Redirect"
                });
            }
            catch (UserSpecificException use)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    Exception = true,
                    Message = use.Message,
                    Type = "Error"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    Exception = true,
                    Message = GlobalMsgResource.Something_Went_Wrong,
                    Type = "Error"
                });
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("failed");
        }
```

Comment: so show how you assign that value

Comment: Here is the function..

Comment: Havent you tried to  `console.log(getQualityDetailList)` at each stage (before and after) where you mutate `getQualityDetailList ` ? This would probably answer ur question

Comment: And always include in your snippets your console.logs and results, so you wont waste others time..